# How to prove this function is measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, measurable-functions

Suppose $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of measurable functions on $[0,1]$. For any $x \in [0,1]$, suppose that $\exists$ $N$ s.t. $f_n(x)=0$ for all $n\ge N$. Define function $h$ as the smallest index $n$ for which $f_n(x)=0$, i.e. $h(x) = inf\{n:f_n(x)=0\}$.

If I want to show that h is measurable function, what should I do?

Actually, I've tried a lot. I thought my definition of $g_n := \chi_{\{0\}}(f_n(x))$ is good because it used the condition that $\{f_n\}$ is measurable, but not useful to prove it. Or definition? But I still don't know how to show the inverse is a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: I'm curious about the phrasing: in the definition of $h(x),$ is the condition just $\inf \{n : f_n(x) = 0 \},$ or is it $\inf \{n : \forall m \geq n, f_m(x) = 0\}$?

Comment: Thank for your curiousity. Actually, I'm also confused by this as this is a given question. If it's the latter one, I think my definition of $g_n$ will be quite useful. But, frankly speaking, I have no idea about how to relate the first condition to the question. For example, when $x=0$, $f_1=1, f_2 =2, f_3=0, f_4=2, f_5 = 0, \dots$, it seems that $h(0)$ equals to 3, but, is it useful? I'm confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have
$$h^{-1} (\{k\}) =\{x\in [0,1] :\inf\{n: f_n (x) =0\} =k\}=f_k^{-1} (\{0\} ) \setminus \left(\bigcup_{1\leq j\leq k-1} f_j^{-1} (\{0\} )\right)$$
and since the functions $f_j$ are mesurable therefore $h^{-1} (\{k\}) $ is measurable for any $k\in\mathbb{N}.$
Now since $h$ attains only natural values the above implies measurability of $h$.